# How I can use random with CQRS+Event Sourcing

Tags: c#, mongodb, cqrs, event-sourcing

I write my project, which is forum's game Mafia. I use CQRS Event Sourcing + MongoDB. When the game is starting, the game needs to give each player his a random role. How I can realize it, if when aggregate root will be applied event ,for example, "roles given", from DB (not event, which has been saved now ) , always will be call random function, which will be return different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can realize it, if when aggregate root will be applied event ,for example, "roles given", from DB (not event, which has been saved now ) , always will be call random function, which will be return different result?

Creating events and applying events are different code paths.  There is no "thinking" to be done when applying an event, because the aggregate already did the thinking when creating the event.  All you need to do in apply is faithfully update your state.

Which is to say, it's not the job of the aggregate to enforce the rules when applying events.

So your history would look something like

```
GameStarted()
RoleAssigned(Alice, Innocent)
RoleAssigned(Bob, Innocent)
RoleAssigned(Charlie, Mafia)
...
```

Notice that there's nothing random to do; you rehydrate the state of your game without worrying whether those events originally described random assignments - because the assignment happened in the past, the assignment is completely determined *now*.

The random bits of the assignment belong on the write path, when the aggregate is making the decision

```
void assignRole(Player p) {
    Role role = getRandomRole();
    this.apply( RoleAssigned(p, role) );
}
```

**Followup**

> How should I change my code?

```
class GameEventHandler { 
    public void Handle(GameStartedEvent message) { 
        var randomRoles =_randomizer.GetRandomRoles(); 

        foreach(user in userAggregates) { 
            user.RoleAssign(new AssignRoleCommand(randomRoles[i] ));
        } 
    } 
}
```

Decision making code in an event handler is a "code smell"; it's a clue that something has gone wrong somewhere.  Choices should be made in your model when an aggregate handles a command.

For something like Mafia, where you will want to have the right balance of roles, and need to worry about which variant rules you are using when assigning the roles, I would expect the `Game` aggregate to own the role assignment decision.  Therefore, the random assignment would happen in the StartGameCommand handler, and might look something like this

```
class Game {
    public void startGame () {
        this.apply(GameStarted());

        var randomRoles =_randomizer.GetRandomRoles(); 

        foreach(userId in this.players) {
            this.apply(RoleAssigned(userId, randomRoles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The list of events that we saw before are all here, being written as the result of running one single command (which means that all of them get written to your event store in a single transaction).

On the other hand, if you really needed each user aggregate to be responsible for assigning its role, then this logic here would be broken up like so

```
class Game {
    public void startGame () {
        this.apply(GameStarted(this.players));
    }
}

class User {
    public void assignRole () {
        this.apply(RoleAssigned(this.id, _randomizer.getRandomRole());
    }
}
```

And your event handler would bridge the two, without knowing anything about the random roles.

```
class GameEventHandler { 
    public void Handle(GameStartedEvent message) { 
        foreach(userId in message.players) { 
            dispatch(AssignRoleCommand(userId));
        } 
    } 
}
```

Event handlers are like managers, they don't do anything, they just delegate work to others

Comment: ok, but I call it   into
      `class GameEventHandler
{
  public void Handle(GameStartedEvent message)
 {
     var randomRoles =_randomizer.GetRandomRoles();

     foreach(user in userAggregates) { 
     user.RoleAssign(new AssignRoleCommand(randomRoles[i] ))
     }
 }
}` and it means , that always when gameAggregate will be apply event GameStarted , randomizer send random role. How should I change my code?

Comment: Or it(assigning roles randomly) must be only manually  made once?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily you would have a command that would trigger some domain behaviour (I.e. assign the random role) and then the role would be saved in an event in the database, I.e. `RoleAssigned`. This would preserve the role when the player next resumes the game by replaying the events. You wouldn't assign the random role in the code that handles the event, it would be done in the command handler, which isn't replayed.

```
public void Handle<StartGameCommand>()
{
     var player = someEventSourcedPlayerRepository.GetOrCreateOrWhatever();
     player.assignRole(); // randomly assigns the role and creates event RoleAssigned
     someEventSourcedPlayerRepository.Save(); // saves events to db
}
```

In the code above, the player will have an event with their role in. When you next load the player, their role is taken from the event. You do not call player.assignRole again.

Comment: Yes, I understand you, but if I want , that role assign is automatically. In my project commands and command handlers change a state of the system when I send the request. If I want, that smth to be automatically, I write it in Event Handlers, but then it will be written to BD. How am I supposed to do? (Sorry for my terrible English)

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the role to be assigned once only? If so, do it in the command handler flow as I describe. It is still automatic - that bit should be the same logic wherever it goes.

Comment: @tomliversidge alternatively, you could generate a random AssignRole command and execute it. Admittedly, this would be a business transaction and prevent the whole GameStart from being a single, atomic transaction. But depending on your style of Event Sourcing, you might have to enforce a strict 1 "modified" AR = 1 transaction anyway and if the AR is `Player`, scope will remain small anyway.